# How does a voltage source know what intensity to give? How much time does it take to measure and know?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage, batteries

as the title says, how does a battery use V = IR in measuring the intensity it would give, or is the voltage the variable here? if it's the voltage, what does that even mean?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple explanation. A voltage source is characterized by an emf (electromotive force).  For example, in a chemical battery, the emf is due to chemical reactions in the battery.  The emf is determined by the type of source and is fixed.  This emf creates a voltage difference at the output terminals of the source.  When an external load, a resistor for your case, is connected across the output terminals, the voltage difference in the source pushes charges through the resistor, creating a current flow in the resistor.    For your case, $V$ and $R$ are fixed and $I$ is determined by $V = IR$, Ohm's law. The voltage is determined by the emf, and the current is determined by the magnitude of the resistance. (When current flows, the voltage at the output terminals of the source is slightly less than the emf due to losses within the source (internal impedance) when it provides current; for a dc source loss this is modeled using an internal resistance in the source.   That is, $ V = emf - IR_{internal}$.)

The same idea applies to ac circuits: an emf produces a voltage difference. For example, the emf may be from an ac generator, and the external load can be impedance (resistance/capacitance/inductance circuit elements) and perhaps a motor driving an external mechanical load.

Comment: is there some equation that describes how much time does it take for the intensity to be determined? or rather how exactly it is determined, other than mathematically? is there something that checks the whole circuit for total impedance, calculate it, and then make the source spit out the suitable intensity? that's the bit i don't yet understand

Comment: Maxwell's equations describe the details, but they are not easy to understand or apply.  Basically, electromagnetic changes propagate at the speed of light.  Perhaps an expert on electromagnetism on this exchange can provide more information.

Comment: I'll search more about this, thanks for pointing this out